Data Not Appearing in Athena View Tables Created via Terraform
I am creating view tables in AWS Athena using Terraform. These view tables should be populated with data from fact and dimension tables I also created via Terraform. However, while the view tables are created successfully and appear in Athena, they do not contain any data. When I try to "Preview" the view in Athena, I get the following error: GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: No value present
This query ran against the ‘athena_database’ database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id:
What I’ve Tried

Using aws_athena_named_query Resource: Initially, I attempted to create the views using the aws_athena_named_query Terraform resource but encountered issues.

Using Glue: I then created the fact and dimension tables, as well as the views, via Glue. While the tables and views are created successfully, the data does not populate the views.

The views work perfectly when created manually via SQL queries in the AWS Console.

The issue arises only when creating the views using Terraform/Glue.


Terraform Code look like this
data "local_file" "views" {
  filename = "${path.module}/views.json"
}

locals {
  views = jsondecode(data.local_file.views.content).views
}

resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "views_table" {
  for_each = { for v in local.views : v.name => v }

  name          = each.value.name
  database_name = aws_glue_catalog_database.primary_database.name
  table_type    = "VIRTUAL_VIEW"

  parameters = {
    "view_expanded_text" = each.value.query
    "view_original_text" = each.value.query
    #"classification"     = "VIEW"
    "presto_view"        = "true"
  }

  storage_descriptor {
    dynamic "columns" {
      for_each = each.value.columns
      content {
        name = columns.value.name
        type = columns.value.type
      }
    }
  }
}

Views.json

{
  "views": [
    {
      "name": "vw_documents_category",
      "query": "SELECT split_part(file_name, '/', 1) AS parent, (CASE WHEN (cardinality(split(file_name, '/')) < 2) THEN split_part(file_name, '/', 1) ELSE split_part(file_name, '/', 2) END) AS middle, (CASE WHEN (cardinality(split(file_name, '/')) > 2) THEN split_part(file_name, '/', 3) WHEN (cardinality(split(file_name, '/')) < 2) THEN split_part(file_name, '/', 1) ELSE split_part(file_name, '/', 2) END) AS child, id FROM database.vw_fact_chat_request_history WHERE file_name IS NOT NULL",
      "columns": [
        { "name": "parent", "type": "string" },
        { "name": "middle", "type": "string" },
        { "name": "child", "type": "string" },
        { "name": "id", "type": "string" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "vw_source_chunks",
      "query": "SELECT session_id, message_id, file_name, MIN(page) AS min_page, CONCAT('s3://s3-bucket/Documents/Live/', REPLACE(file_name, ' ', '%20')) AS file_link FROM database.fact_chat_request_source_chunks GROUP BY session_id, message_id, file_name",
      "columns": [
        { "name": "session_id", "type": "string" },
        { "name": "message_id", "type": "string" },
        { "name": "file_name", "type": "string" },
        { "name": "min_page", "type": "int" },
        { "name": "file_link", "type": "string" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "vw_dim_feedback",
      "query": "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_dim_feedback AS SELECT id feedback_id, \"values\" feedback FROM database.dim_feedback;",
      "columns": [
        { "name": "feedback_id", "type": "int" },
        { "name": "feedback", "type": "string" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Questions:

Why are the views not being populated with data when created via Terraform?
Is there an additional step or configuration required for the data to populate these views?
Are there known issues with Glue or Terraform when creating Athena views?

